# add subview to cell

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

i trying to make custom view on black opaque. In this view i need table view with cells and textfields inside. so when i make this, i have slow fps and text :

```
setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)

 static NSString *textfield = @"textfield";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textfield];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:textfield];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
            textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            textField.placeholder = placeholderName;
            textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0f];
            textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0f/255.0f green:68.0f/255.0f blue:68.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
            textField.tag = curTag;
            textField.text = @"aads";

            [_fields setObject:textField forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curTag]];

            [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
            [textField becomeFirstResponder];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
        }
```

i also trying

```
        [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:textField];
```

and

[cell.contentView.window addSubview:textField];

but then i haven't uitextfield inside cell T_T

How i create view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _currentPage = 0;
        _fields = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [[PopupData inst] loadNewPortfolioPopupData];

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPopupView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:_view];

        [self mainPopupNavi];
//        _tableView.bounces = NO;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a proper UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: to maintain a sane view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, the problem is most likely that your textfield has a size of 0. You are assigning it a size based on the size of the cell, but at the point you are doing it, the cell has a size of 0.

If you add

`textField.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

after you size up the text field, that should do it. This will resize the text field automatically once its superview is resized. So once the cell is prepared for display the textfield will resize with it.

Comment: I put as you said, but again, with subviewtofront it's not appear on cell, and with addsubview again text "setting the first..." don't know what to do T_T